# Request feedback on my unet training: is this underfitting or overfitting?

Tags: neural-networks

The more I read, the more I am confused as to how to interpret the validation and training loss graphs, so therefore I would like to ask for some guidance on how to interpret these values here in the picture. I am training a basic UNet architecture. I am now wondering if I need a more complex network model, or that I just need more data to improve the accuracy.

Historical note: I had the issue where validation loss was exploding after a few epochs, but I added dropout layers and that seems to have fixed the situation.

My current interpretation is that the validation loss is slowly increasing, so does that mean that it's useless to train further? Or should I rather let it train further because the validation accuracy seems to sometimes jump up a little bit?

[image: Tensorboard of training]